# How to read hexadecimal value from xml file using java

Tags: java, mysql, hex, blob

i am trying to fetch data from xml file using java.

using mysqldump the database table is converted to xml.

table contains one field which is in BLOB type.

Table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `image` BLOB
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Back up data with hexadecimal value using following procedure

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppassword test test --compact --no-create-info --hex-blob > check.sql --xml
```

in xml blob field content is in hexadecimal values.

Java code that i tried is

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {

        File fXmlFile = new File("E:\\check.sql");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("row");
        System.out.println("-----------------------");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                System.out.println(" Image " + getTagValueUsingAttributeName("field","image", eElement));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private static String getTagValueUsingAttributeName(String sTag, String attributeName, Element eElement){
    String value="";
    for(int i=0;i<eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).getLength();i++){            
        if((eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getTextContent()).equalsIgnoreCase(attributeName)){
            System.out.println(" - "+eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getTextContent());
            NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(i).getChildNodes();
            System.out.println(1);
            Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);
            if(nValue!=null)
                System.out.println(2+" - "+(nValue.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE));
            value = (nValue==null)?" ":nValue.getTextContent();
            break;
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

But i can not read the xml file for parsing.

Note :
  I tried to put the xml file in stackoverflow but it does not allow me to add xml content.

please help me.

Comment: You should be able to post XML data, so long as you do it properly within a code block or similar.  Otherwise they'll be interpreted as HTML tags and effectively ignored.

Comment: Anyway, what's the specific problem that you're running into?  Since you said "I can not read the XML file for parsing", I can only conclude that `E:\check.sql` doesn't exist based on the information you've given.  Also, this is nothing to do with hexadecimal right, you're just asking about problems reading a file?

Comment: 'E:\check.sql' is the file generated by mysqldump (i specified in code tag)

Comment: OK, great - maybe you don't have permissions to read it then.  Since my crystal ball is at the repair shop, I can't help you without further information about the error you're getting.  "I can not read the XML file" could be just about anything.

Comment: "I can not read the XML file" means i unable to read xml fully. at the same time i able to read content before starting the hexadecimal values

Comment: Yes, but **why**?  Do you get an exception?  If so, which one and with what error message, and at what point?  If you don't get an exception, what makes you think the whole file hasn't been read - which variables are you inspecting, at which point, what values do they *have* and what did you *expect*?

Comment: No, am did not get any exception. i think, hexa decimal values alone is not reading. i checked with normal contents. this is the problem iam still having.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to decode long value encoded as Hex you could use this class: http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html

For example, if you have your value stored in char[] array you may use `Hex.decodeHex(char[] data)` to convert it into raw byte[] array. I'm assuming that you you're treating your BLOB as binary content.

Comment: i do not want to decode values. just i am trying to read the content from xml.

Comment: So, you're trying to parse XML file. This is a different topic. Try this: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2000/jw-0804-sax.html